# pt-online-schema-change with statement based replication in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, schema, percona-tools, percona-toolkit

Is it possible/safe to use pt-online-schema-change in a Master slave environment where as the way replication is setup is statement based(SBR).

What is the better way of doing it as currently I have 10 slaves and a Master.

Comment: should be safe. pt-osc is designed to work in replication topologies. What is your concern?

Comment: My only concern is in Statement based replication, when master is done with the table the slave will replay it. Would the slave lock the table or would act just like the master and have table available for reads and also changes from the master ?

Comment: Pt-osc on a slave progresses along with the master. Both the slaves and the master are blocked for a short period of time when pt-osc swaps the tables